# Android Studio : Unknown host

Tags: android, android-studio

Facing the following issue with Android Studio after an update today.

**Error**

```
Unknown host 'This is usually a temporary error during hostname resolution and means that the local server did not receive a response from an authoritative server'. You may need to adjust the proxy settings in Gradle.

Enable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project

Learn about configuring HTTP proxies in Gradle
```

When I click on "Enable offline mode", get the following error:

```
Error:No cached version of com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.14.1 available for offline mode.
Disable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project
```

**What I have tried:**

Options are based on other posts/ suggestions:

a. File > Settings > Build, Execution, Developement > Gradle

Selected the right folder for Gradle.

b. Updated build.gradle file (Project file and NOT Module)

```
    //classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.14.1'
```

Despite these changes .. the error persists.

Any help or suggestions .. thanks in advance !

Comment: *This is usually a temporary error*

Comment: Do you need a proxy to access internet in your network?

Comment: I don't use a proxy to connect to internet .. but need an 'automatic configuration script' in the : Internet Options > Connections > LAN Settings section.

Answer (score 0):

When I update to 1.5.1 the classpath was

classpath `com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3`

It give me error like yours.

I tried to change it to

classpath `com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.1`

It didn't work but when I change it to

classpath `com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0`

It worked.
So you should give it a shot play with the numbers it might work.

Answer (score 0):

1. File > Settings > Build, Execution, Developement > Gradle>Experimental> Check: "Allow Module selection on project import"
   2.Sync Gradle again